# can we select only particular columns in ADF Dataflow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

So I have some data, but I only want some particular columns to be selected. Is there any way to do that in ADF dataflow?

I have tried Select activity but it is giving all the columns. How to get only particular columns?

> **Edit: got The answer.  Fixed Mapping is the way to do it. If anyone have better solutions , let me know***

Comment: Select activity is the correct one, can you show what you've tried?

Comment: in select transformation there is delete option to delete the columns which you don't want in sink. all defined columns will have a fixed mapping by default in data flow.

Answer (score 0):

> I only want some particular columns to be selected. Is there any way to do that in ADF dataflow?

**Select transformation takes all columns from incoming stream. To select particular column from select transformation you can select a and delete the unwanted column as shown below image.**

[image]

And also, there are two mappings to map the columns:

- **Fixed Mapping (default)**
- **Rule based Mapping**

You can use rule-based mapping to construct your mappings using column patterns if you want to map many columns at once or send drifting columns downstream. **Matching is done using the column names, types, streams, and positions**.